# HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

I'm developing dynamic java project using spring mvc and angularjs. This project is successfully running on Ubuntu system. But in windows this project is not running.

I'm using tomcat 7. All the required jar under lib folder. After project is successfully build, it throws exception.

I checked related question on stack overflow, but my problem is not resloved. I tried to reslove this issue more than one week, but I can't reslove this issue.

Thank you, looking positive replay..!

**Stack Trace:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1282)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

**Root Cause:**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getUserPrincipal(RequestFacade.java:828)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:184)
```

Comment: What is the value of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getUserPrincipal()?

Comment: thank you for your reply @mikep i don't know

Answer (score 0):

You are running into an recursive loop. An example for this is (pseudo code):

```
void causeStackOverflow() {
    if (a == b) { // which is never the case
        return;
    } else {
        causeStackOverflow();
    }
}
```

Basically you have to find out why the code on in HttpServletRequestWrapper.java on line 184 calls itself again and again and fix your code logic there.

If you want to have some help on that you'll have to post code

Comment: HttpServletRequestWrapper.java this class contains servlet api.jar . i didn't find that line

Comment: you may use a decompiler to look at the code logic then, maybe you will find something that can help you

Comment: same project running another system. in this system also project build successful. web page not open in browser.

Comment: there are a LOT of differences between linux and windows. to resolve your issue you'll have to debug the code and find the cause that causes the library to have an stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

When configuring springMVC, I found that maven dependencies that do not add JSTL will cause this problem, at least for my view parser, but I do not know if you are or not, springMVC, is the same error. View resolver problem